# Copying sections of one picture to another

Tags: image, jython

I have two solutions (in Jython) to take two pictures and copy and paste alternate sections of one picture to the other, like so:

[image: pic1][image: pic2][image: newpic]

```
for x in range (0,w):
  for y in range (0,h):
    sourcePx=getPixel(pic1,x,y)
    targetPx=getPixel(pic2,x,y)
    if (y>=0 and y<20) or (y>=40 and y<60)or (y>=80 and y<=100):
      setColor(targetPx, getColor(sourcePx))
repaint (pic2)
```

---

```
for y in range(0,h):
  leaf = (y>=0 and y<20) or (y>=40 and y<60)or (y>=80 and y<=100):
  if leaf:
    for x in range(width):
      sourcePx = getPixel(pic1, x, y)
      targetPx = getPixel(pic2, x, y)
      setColor(targetPx, getColor(sourcePx))
  repaint(pic2)
```

---

I have been trying to work this out and have two questions about this:

1. Which is the more efficient way to loop through the pixels and why?
2. Does it make any difference to efficiency (and if so how), creating the variable leaf and then using that in the `if` statement?

Comment: Minor point (not worth an answer): You an rewrite `(y>=0 and y<20)` to `0 <= y < 20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is more efficient. Simply because in the first one you are calculating the `if` `w * h` times but in the second you are calculating it `h` times.

Also it can be made more readable and efficient just by using this. It eliminates `leaf` which you aren't using anywhere. Readability doesn't need explaining.

```
for y in range(0,h):
  if (20 > y >= 0) or (60 > y >= 40)or (100 >= y >= 80):
    for x in range(width):
      sourcePx = getPixel(pic1, x, y)
      targetPx = getPixel(pic2, x, y)
      setColor(targetPx, getColor(sourcePx))
  repaint(pic2)
```

**Update 1**

As limelights has suggested, use of `xrange` is better than use of `range` in Python2. If your `h` or `w` are big then using `range` would return a list which occupies memory while use of `xrange` returns a generator which is much more memory efficient. Performance might suffer a bit but in most cases it is worth it.

Comment: ty Aseem, yes I can see what you are saying about the loops, for some reason I can stare at something and it's like a brain jam and I can't figure out the simplest of concepts.. cheers

Comment: This could be optimised even further, just FYI. The use of `xrange()` for example if width is massive would speed the program up.

Comment: @limelights I have been using Python 3 for some time and forgot that unless Python3 tag is used questions are about 2 not 3. I'll add that. Thanks.

Comment: Not worth an answer but... I would start it with `for y in range(20) + range(40, 60) + range(80, 100)` which seems cleaner than having an if condition.